# Passing arguments in Python and its hierarchy

Tags: python-2.7

Is there any hierarchy to pass arguments in python..?

```
>>>def anyFun(a,tuple,dictionary)
```

Should we pass int/str then tuple and then dictionary.

```
>>>def anyFun1(dictionary,tuple,a)
```

Should we pass int/str then dictionary and then tuple

```
>>>def anyFun2(tuple,a,dictionary)
```

Should we pass tuple then int/str and then dictionary.

or we can pass the arguments in python as in other programming languages.
Please help me on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is python is quite limited. But as far as I know, the order you pass the arguments to a function won't really 'cause any major effects.

Comment: There is a difference if we do not pass the argument in proper sequence .

Comment: @bittu sorry wrong choice of words. What I meant is that the order of arguments to be passed when we define a function doesn't matter. Whether we define our function to accept a `tuple` or an `int` first doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
have a function with arguments as Tuple and Dictionary:
def fo(*args,**li):
     print args
     print "args is of type:",type(args)#->is a tuple
     print li 
     print "**li is of type:",type(li) #-> ** is dictionary 
fo( a=8,b=9,c='as',1,3,4,)
Output : Will throw an error 

Correct way to pass an argument(in this case Tuple and Dictionary) :
fo(1,3,4, a=8,b=9,c='as')
Output: 
(1, 3, 4)
args is of type: <type 'tuple'>
{'a': 8, 'c': 'as', 'b': 9}
**li is of type: <type 'dict'>
```